# Hypledger farbric: RPC error (Identity or token does not match) on restart of peers

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have setup hypledger fabric 0.6 on a local development using docker-toolbox and vagrant. The first time I ran the four-peer-ca.yaml example using the command

```
docker-compose -f four-peer-ca.yaml up
```

Four-peer-ca.yaml file is available on:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/v0.6/examples/docker-compose

Everything worked well. However when exited this docker compose task and tried to run the command again I received the below error:

```
vp1_1         | 10:29:42.752 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 01b [validator.test_vp1] Failed invoking CreateCertficatePair [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.752 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 01c [validator.test_vp1] Failed getting enrollment certificate [id=test_vp1]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.752 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 01d [validator.test_vp1] Failed retrieving enrollment data [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.752 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 01e [validator.test_vp1] Failed registering node crypto engine [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.755 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 01f [validator.test_vp1] Failed registering peer [test_vp1]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.755 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 020 [validator.test_vp1] Failed registering [test_vp1]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]

vp1_1         | 10:29:42.755 [crypto] RegisterValidator -> ERRO 021 Failed registering validator [test_vp1] with name [test_vp1] [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].
```

Closing and restarting the virtual box didn't help. Anyone has an idea how what is causing the above error and how it can be resolved?

Comment: How did you exit the docker compose task? I used to receive the error "Identity or token does not match." when the credentials were already used/logged in

Answer (score 1):

Using the `docker-compose -f four-peer-ca.yaml down` command should stop any running docker containers for this compose file and remove the containers. This should remove any already existing crypto material in the peers and CA, and you should be able to run the `docker-compose -f four-peer-ca.yaml up` again.

Comment: Or delete all containers.